# Progress REST PUT in classic server returns error

Tags: rest, web-services, put, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a test table called `Cities`. Creation script is as follows:

```
ADD TABLE "Cities"
  AREA "Schema Area"
  LABEL "Cities"
  DUMP-NAME "Cities"

ADD FIELD "ID" OF "Cities" AS integer
  DESCRIPTION "ID"
  INITIAL 0
  LABEL "ID"
  COLUMN-LABEL "ID"
  ORDER 10

ADD FIELD "City" OF "Cities" AS character
  DESCRIPTION "City name"
  FORMAT "x(30)"
  INITIAL ""
  LABEL "Cities"
  MAX-WIDTH 30
  COLUMN-LABEL "Cities"
  ORDER 20

ADD INDEX "IxID" ON "Cities" 
  AREA "Schema Area"
  UNIQUE
  PRIMARY
  INDEX-FIELD "ID" ASCENDING 
.
PSC
cpstream=1250
.
0002253205
```

I have added one record to this table:

```
create Cities.
assign
    Cities.ID = 1
    Cities.City = "Boston".
```

`FOR EACH` routine shows proper result with one record.

I have created some REST project with classic server settings for learning and testing purposes. All servers and configurations are standard as installator configured them.
I have added some procedures to AppServer folder (file: test.p) and created temp-table within it. Full procedure code:

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCities LIKE Cities.

@openapi.openedge.export(type="REST", useReturnValue="false", writeDataSetBeforeImage="false").
PROCEDURE readCities:

    DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER TABLE FOR ttCities.

    FOR EACH Cities NO-LOCK:
        CREATE ttCities.
        BUFFER-COPY Cities TO ttCities.
    END.

END PROCEDURE.

@openapi.openedge.export(type="REST", useReturnValue="false", writeDataSetBeforeImage="false").
PROCEDURE putCities:

    DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER TABLE FOR ttCities.

END PROCEDURE.
```

Procedure compiles well, annotations are added by `Define Service Interface` functionality in OpenEdge.
In `Defined Services` node I have created mappings for parameters (I will omit `readCities` because it works well) for `putCities` and PUT verb:

1. Resources: `/PutCities`
2. Verb Association: `Verb='PUT'` -> test..putCities
3. Mapping Definitions for Input: parameter ttCities is connected to request `HTTP Message -> Body` section directly (not to body parameter)
4. Mapping Definitions for Output: response ttCities is connected to `Interface Parameters -> ttCities`

My client code is very basic - taken from some Progress KB article and project has `OpenEdge.Net.pl` libraries included in PROPATH:

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

USING Progress.Json.ObjectModel.JsonObject.
USING Progress.Json.ObjectModel.*.
USING Progress.Json.ObjectModel.ObjectModelParser.
USING Progress.Lang.Object.
USING OpenEdge.Core.WidgetHandle.
USING OpenEdge.Core.String.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.IHttpRequest.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.IHttpResponse.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.ClientBuilder.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.RequestBuilder.
DEFINE VARIABLE oRequest  AS IHttpRequest  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE oResponse AS IHttpResponse NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE oEntity   AS Object        NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lcHTML    AS LONGCHAR      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hXmlDoc   AS HANDLE        NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hCities AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE oJson AS JsonObject NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lReturnValue AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCities LIKE Cities.

hCities = TEMP-TABLE ttCities:HANDLE.

create ttCities.
assign
    ttCities.ID = 1
    ttCities.City = "Boston".

oJson = NEW JsonObject().
lReturnValue = oJson:Read(hCities).

oRequest = RequestBuilder:Put('http://127.0.0.1:8980/REST6/rest/REST6/PutCities', oJson):Request.
oResponse = ClientBuilder:Build():Client:Execute(oRequest).

MESSAGE oResponse:StatusCode oResponse:StatusReason VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

/* some other code to parse response */
```

This code compiles well, but calling it give this error:
`Cities already exists with ID 1.`

I suppose that procedure is called on the server but can't update DB record because of this error. As far as I know calling PUT method should perform update on record - not creating new one. In addition changing `ttCities.ID` to value 2 creates new record.

So my question is simple: how to handle with this? Should I write my own custom logic in `putCities` procedure?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that the message means what it says.  You are attempting to create a city that already exists.  You show the definition of the table and then say that you manually added city 1, Boston and that FOR EACH shows that it exists in the db.  You don't mention that you have deleted it  -- so what happens if you change the ttCities.ID to 2 and ttCities.City to "New York"?

Comment: Dear Mr Bascom, as I said when ID = 2 new record is created correctly. And You are right - I haven't deleted record with ID = 1. But in general I think that I make some mistakes caused by .NET ORMs... I think about PUT in different way that I should... ORMs take care about PUT operation by themselves so I don't have to think about any custom logic in methods. That's my bad ofcourse.

Comment: Mea culpa.  I somehow didn’t see the part where you already tried id = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is as follows:

You create your temp-table "like" your database table so it inherits the unique index as well as the table friendly name of "Cities". 
Your ReadCities creates a temp table record for each database record, so we have one with an ID of 1.

Your client code though, creates a temp-table record with ID 1, but then heads off to the ReadCities code and gets all the database records, and at that point you get the error as there is already a temp-table record there with an ID of 1.

You can probably prove this by putting messages in your code to determine at what point the error is received. I imagine that if you put a message before "lReturnValue = oJson:Read(hCities)." and another after it, that you will get the first message before the error.

Comment: I could get this kind of message from my temp-table - it's true, but I got it from DB (look on table name in my description - it's `Cities` not `ttCities`). But You directed my to proper solution - creating temp-table with `LIKE` clause is a problem in this case, because temp-table created this way is linked with target table. I can do it on client side and code works OK, but on server side it should be defined manually in code. Thank You.